# Determine parameters of a Service Stack rest call

Tags: rest, servicestack

I am looking into porting some code to go through a Service Stack layer instead of direct database access. I have created a service that descends from RestServiceBase. In my override of OnGet, is there a way to know what parameters if any were passed to the rest call? In the example on the Service Stack site, they show comparing a field against the default value, but in my case, 0 is a valid identifier (legacy behavior) so I can't tell from that value whether to search for a single item, or return all items.

Answer (score 1):

If the default value of a type is a valid identifier, you should make the property nullable.

```
public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
```

Now in the service you can check if the value is `0` or `null`. If it's `null`, the property wasn't passed with the request.

Comment: I had thought of that, but I'd rather not make that change since it isn't valid to have a null identifier. It's a smell to me that I would need to change my DTO just to support querying. I may end up just changing to a request/response service to give me the flexibility to have a different request and response DTO.

Comment: You can also check for existence if the parameter was passed in the request, i.e: `base.Request.QueryString["Age"]` or `.FormData[]` or `GetParam()` ext method that looks through everything